# how/where to add token in http get request in Rest Debugger Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi

web-service has token parameter. In swagger and postman I send get-request properly (status 200). In Poastman creating request is very easy because it has separate pages for parameters and headers.

As for Rest Debugger I couldn't create and sent right get-request( appears error 400).
I tried many ways but without success:

1. I write token in request parameter section of Rest Debugger as key-value pair like "token"= "abcd12345..."
   or
2. I write base URL and resouce together in URL-field like:
   https://testserver.com/currencies?token=abcd12345..... or
3. I write resource separately in resouce field of Rest Debugger and base -URL in URL-field

but in all cases server returns error 400:

> "the token field is required".

screens of swagger, curl, postman and rest debugger.

[image: swagger and Postman][image: Rest Debugger]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suppose that a better solution is to use Postman for this task, if it works as expected and is more user-friendly. But if it’s principal thing – you can do it in Rest Debugger.

Go to the “parameters” tab -> click the “Add” button -> change “Kind” field to “HEADER” -> “Name” field to ‘’token” -> “value” to your token value.
You can see that in Postman you use a header to send token value, but in Rest Debugger simple param – that’s why you get different results.

Comment: Postman is for testing Purpose, I don't think that he can archive what he wants with Postman. And your Answer is exact the Same as mine, just 2 hours later, so...

Comment: @Softacom it works. Rest Debugger I choose because I may easy copy Rest-components when click on button "copy components" in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define it as header.
Use Parameter section and use `[HEADER]` instead of `[GET/POST]`